# how to show time 08:00:00 to 8 am using swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I'm receiving time in string as 08:00:00 and I need to show it as 8 am.
I have no idea how to do it so guys help me.

I don't know how to do it using NSDate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *sample = @"08:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  // or use hh:mm:ss
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sample];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH a"];  // or use hh
 NSString *finaldate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
  NSLog(@"%@",finaldate);
```

**Swift**

```
var sample: String = "08:00:00"
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"  // or use hh:mm:ss
var date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(sample)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH a"  // or use hh
var finaldate: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date1)
NSLog("%@", finaldate)
```

**Time Format**

```
// 24 hours fomat
HH  -- 13, 14, etc 
// 12 hours format
 hh  -- 01, 02, etc
```

Comment: awesome
worked 
print(" formattedDate  \(finaldate)")

Comment: but if time is         let sample: String = "08:45:00" then it still show 08 am 
but in this case don't you tink it should be 08:45 am ?

Comment: well i got it         dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
i'm kind of in hurry , thank you so much

Comment: But again 
        let sample: String = "18:00:00"
it show 18:00 pm , don't you think it should be 6:00 pm

Comment: can you tell me why it is showing 18:00 pm not 6 pm

Comment: @MandeepKumar - change this `HH a` into `h a` or try `hh a`.

Comment: i got it 
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"